# Reading and writing a buffer in binary file

Tags: c, fopen

Here is my code as of now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "readwrite.h"

int main ()
{   FILE* pFile;
    char buffer[] = {'x' ,'y','z',0};
    pFile = fopen("C:\\Test\\myfile.bin","wb");

    if (pFile ){
        fwrite(buffer,1,sizeof(buffer),pFile); 

    printf("The buffer looks like: %s",buffer);
  }
    else
    printf("Can't open file");


   fclose(pFile);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to write something verify i wrote to the file and then read from the file and verify i read from the file. How best is there to do this? I also need to figure out a way to write the same thing to 2 different files. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
FILE* pFile;
char* yourFilePath  = "C:\\Test.bin";
char* yourBuffer    = "HelloWorld!";
int   yorBufferSize = strlen(yourBuffer) + 1;

/* Reserve memory for your readed buffer */
char* readedBuffer = malloc(yorBufferSize);

if (readedBuffer==0){
    puts("Can't reserve memory for Test!");
}

/* Write your buffer to disk. */
pFile = fopen(yourFilePath,"wb");

if (pFile){
    fwrite(yourBuffer, yorBufferSize, 1, pFile);
    puts("Wrote to file!");
}
else{
    puts("Something wrong writing to File.");
}

fclose(pFile);

/* Now, we read the file and get its information. */
pFile = fopen(yourFilePath,"rb");

if (pFile){
    fread(readedBuffer, yorBufferSize, 1, pFile);
    puts("Readed from file!");
}
else{
    puts("Something wrong reading from File.\n");
}

/* Compare buffers. */
if (!memcmp(readedBuffer, yourBuffer, yorBufferSize)){
    puts("readedBuffer = yourBuffer");
}
else{
    puts("Buffers are different!");
}

/* Free the reserved memory. */
free(readedBuffer);

fclose(pFile);
return 0;
```

Regards

Comment: excellent!!! How would i do this if instead i were going to use numbers instead of strings and letterS?

Comment: Numbers, structs, strings... all is a memory block with a memory address. So you could make a cast of this memory blocks to a byte buffer and then write/read to a file without problems. Try something like (char*)&myIntegerVariable to get the myIntegerVariable's address and sizeof(int) to get the variable length. Good luck.

Comment: fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
                     FILE *stream);

so it should be corrected to: 
fwrite(yourBuffer, 1, yorBufferSize, pFile);

Answer (score 1):

The program to read a buffer is almost the same except "rb" for read binary and `fread()` instead of `fwrite()`

Remember you will have to know how big the buffer you are going to read is and have some memory of the right size ready to receive it

Comment: Can i wrap the Buffer size in a #define and change it that way? I need the 0 after whats supposed to be in the buffer so I don't get "junk" when i compile and run. For instance, when i printf with the code above, i see x y and z but then i see junk because it searches for a null.

Comment: @Questioneer, for simple tests that's easiest - later you can detect the file size and learn about malloc. You need the trailing zero becuse that marks the end of string in c and you a printing a string - you could also loop over the buffer and print individual characters