# How to dump DSA_SIG or RSA_SIG

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, openssl

I am using openssl/DSA to generate signature for some data using private key.
and on the other side I am verify data integrity using public key.

In the sample code I am able to do it successfully using DSA_sign and DSA_verify functions.

But I would like to dump signature to a file and transfer it to client along with data.
And verify it at other side.

So I am searching for functions which could read/write DSA_SIG from file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749134/reading-and-writing-a-buffer-in-binary-file). Buffer is your unsigned char* sigret.

Comment: my bad.. i used DSA_do_sign and DSA_do_verify not DSA_sign and DSA_verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DSA_sign` simply puts the signature in a `unsigned char*`, also known as just a bunch of bytes. To write it to disk you can use any example out there.