# Write in a loop into a buffer as binary file (.ts)

Tags: c, fopen, fwrite

I a trying to write data into a .ts file continuously in c programming.

File Source: on streaming video

File destination: `/cache/test/pull_data.ts`

output: file size like below

in 1st iteration pull_data.ts --> file size 1213 bytes

in 2nd iteration pull_data.ts --> file size 1213 + 1213 bytes

in 3ed iteration pull_data.ts --> file size 1213 + 1213 +1213 bytes , --- and so on.

I have written code like below:

```c
#define data_size 1213;

unsigned char sourcebuf[data_size + 1];

int source_size = 0;

FILE * fileopen;

fileopen = fopen("/cache/test/pull_data.ts ", "wb");

if (fileopen == NULL) {

  printf("error : pull_data.ts opening file ");

  exit(1);

} else {

  printf("sucesses : pull_data.ts opening file ");

  fwrite(sourcebuf, source_size, 1, fileopen);

}
```

We use it to get the data continuously from the source. but for me, `pull_data.ts` size is always showing 1213 bytes. How could I loop this function to update -- > current data + comming data in the `pull_data.ts` file?

Comment: What do you think using `"wb"` when you open the file means?

Comment: Do you want to add to the file or overwrite it?

Comment: I need to add with current data like file size 1316+1316+1316+..

Comment: So you want to look up how to *append* to a file.

Comment: yes, append data continuously

Comment: Have a look at the [mode parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) of `fopen`. There's "a" for append.

Comment: @ScottHunter, I got to know for the binary file we need to write "wb" and "rb". I referred to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749134/reading-and-writing-a-buffer-in-binary-file

Comment: That question does not address *appending* to a file.

Comment: You should call `fclose()`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Note that the link you posted refers to the C++ documentation of `fopen`, not the C documentation. As a consequence, the linked page contains information that may be misleading, for example the reference to the C++ filesystem library or `boost::filesystem`. The correct link to the C documentation of that function is [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `mode` parameter, as the commentors have already told you.

By putting `wb`, as specified in the documentation of `fopen`, you are telling fopen to discard any previous content of the file and start from the beginning instead.

What you want, is the mode parameter `ab` (a for 'append') instead, which will open the file and put the write pointer to the end of the file.
The `b` in there means 'binary' which translates to 'Do not treat `\n` in any special way', which is a very good idea if you're dealing with binary files.

There are a number of other flags as well, such as `a+` (open for appending and reading), `r` for readonly and `r+` for reading and writing. All of these will open the file, leaving the contents intact.

Comment: if I put "ab" the file size is getting 0 bytes.

Comment: When do you look at the size? Before the file is closed, its entry in the directory might not reflect the final size due to buffering, for example.

Comment: @GNK Try using `ftell` on your (open) file descriptor after writing and see what that gives you. Other than that, the busybee is absolutely right, unless you call `fclose`, the write may still be 'in memory' only.